# Posting Invoice Lines to Xero using the API with variable Tax Types

Tags: xero-api

We need to post an Invoice to Xero where 2 Invoices Lines might have the same Account Code but 1 has GST applied and the other has no GST.

The API documentation implies we can simply override the Tax Type for the line where the Tax Type doesn't match the Tax Type set on the Account but Xero doesn't seem to like that.

We don't want to have separate accounts for transactions that attract GST and those that don't.

Is there any way around this?

We tried specifying the Account Code and Tax Type on every line.

Comment: If the Account has a default Tax Type of GST Calculated and we specify No GST with the Account on an Invoice Line, Xero ignores the No GST and calculates GST anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an issue with your payload, please can you raise a case with your details using this form https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support/